# OpenGL mathematics (GLM) port for Java

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glm-math

is there any Java port for [GLM library](http://glm.g-truc.net/) ? I'm using LWJGL and I'm missing some nice capabilities of GLM.

I have seen mention about port in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14875512/663068) answer, but I don't know how to contact the person that wrote the answer (no messages on stackoverflow, no possibility to add comment to closed question).

Comment: I think it is a very constructive question ....mainly for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Porting GLM to Java wouldn't really make sense - it is very much a "C++" library.

[This Github repo](https://github.com/jroyalty/jglm/) (found by googling "glm java port opengl matrix") claims to be a "conceptual" port. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I use thus port. It's compact and efficient. Though you're right, without templates it loses the original idea.